# VMWare ESXi VM's pinging

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, ping, esxi

I have 2 VM's in the VLAN18 in my VMWare ESXi 8.0

I wanted to ping the other one but it doens't find it. Now I turned off the firewall and it worked if they are in the same VLAN, now I want my 1 VM to be in VLAN17 and the other one in VLAN18 and ping eachother but I get the message 'Destination host unreachable'. Both VLAN's are in the same vSwitch. (Also sometimes says timed out).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's completely normal – that's the whole purpose of VLANs; they exist to isolate ports from each other. Direct "same subnet" access is only possible between ports (VMs) that are in the same VLAN.

To forward (i.e. route) packets between VLANs, you need a **router**. This could be either a physical router with 802.1Q VLAN support, or a "L3 switch" or "L2+ switch" (which can route IP as well as switch Ethernet), or a VM that's set up to act as a router (again, running an OS that has 802.1Q VLAN support).

- Your Draytek VigorSwitch G2500 is just a plain L2 switch for Ethernet, according to its documentation. Although it has VLAN and IP routing configuration, that seems to be purely for the sake of management access to the switch itself (and apparently its ONVIF support) – it most likely does not forward packets *between* VLANs.
- Your Draytek Vigor 3910 is an IP router and supports 802.1Q VLANs (up to 100 according to its documentation).

In either case the router needs to have a VLAN "trunk" connection (just like ESXi itself). If they're connected through a switch, then both ports on the switch (router and ESXi) need to have all VLANs "tagged". Each 'tagged' VLAN corresponds to a virtual VLAN interface on the router itself (which you'll have to create one by one), while the single 'untagged' VLAN corresponds to the physical Ethernet interface on the router.

(If you decide to use a VM on ESXi as the router, put it in a port-group with the special VLAN ID 4095; that way it will get a full "trunk" connection with all VLANs 'tagged'.)

Most importantly, **each VLAN needs to have a distinct IP network** (address range). When you are configuring the VLAN interfaces on your router, make sure to choose IP networks that do not overlap – treat them as completely separate LANs.

(If they overlap, hosts won't be able to know that the destination is in a different network – just like in your own example, where you're trying to ping a host that's in a different VLAN, but the source host *thinks* the destination is local.)

Comment: Okay so if I'm understanding correct I have to put my server into a switch (I have draytek VigorSwitch G2500) and make the VLAN's on the switch with different ip's?

At the moment I have this put up on my switch
https://gyazo.com/a5c8c45a52ee44041a51061677741ee1

And then go to vlan routing and set up the ip's here?
https://gyazo.com/7dd3b76ab2da723539e8b9325a3246db

Comment: If the switch is capable of IP routing, then yes... but according to the manual of VigorSwitch G2500 it can't do that, it really is just a plain L2 switch. You can try, though, but I suspect that the switch's VLAN IP configuration is just for "management access" (i.e. for accessing the switch's own config – not for forwarding).

Comment: Alright I also have a DrayTek vigor3910, that will be possible right?

Comment: Yes, since the specs for Vigor 3910 say that it's capable of "802.1Q tag based" VLANs (which is what VLAN trunks use), it should work just fine.

Comment: If I go in there do I have to make new VLAN's in the router or will it bring the vlan's from the vmware esxi into it?

Comment: You'll need to configure each VLAN on the router. Since ESXi doesn't support "advertising" trunked VLANs via GVRP, there's no easy way for other devices to see what VLANs exist on a trunk... and more importantly, since it's a router, you'll need to configure an IP subnet for each of those VLANs anyway (and you'll probably want to add DHCP pools, too), so even if it could pull VLAN IDs via GVRP you'd still need manual configuration regardless.

Comment: I want to make it so my server goes into my switch. And into my switch I want my router and laptop connected. Is this possible or do I need to configuer something on my switch first if I wanna do this?

Comment: On the switch, both the "ESXi" port and the "router" port need to have all custom VLAN IDs configured as 'tagged' (except for the regular VLAN 1 which can stay 'untagged'). If the laptop runs Windows, then the "laptop" port needs to be in _one_ VLAN only (whichever you like) and it needs to be 'untagged'.

Comment: Now I wanna set up VLAN10-20 on the router, I did this to setup for now:

Switch port 1, 2, 3, 4. (Tag Trunk Vlan 10-20, untagged 1).

I put my ESXi into port 1, my router into port 3. My laptop into port port  8 (only has untagged 1).

I am gonna set up VLAN10-20 on the router but can I just put them all on 1 port? Example: at p4 I just put on vlan 10-20 with different lans? (https://gyazo.com/687fab7a91cc169f48f95415e6e0203b)
and connect my switch into p4 or do I have to do it on a different way?

Comment: Yes, you can put them on the same port as long as they all have tagging enabled (and with VIDs matching those in ESXi). That's what VLAN trunking _is..._

Comment: And how do I connect to the specific vlan in the vmware esxi vm?

Comment: Put the VM in a port-group with the same VLAN ID.